# How to push history to a specific component by using async fetch in react js

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, fetch

I am writing a login page using reactjs where I am generating my OTP in a separate flask application. I am calling a function on a button click which fetches the API and checks if the OTP is matching or not. It provides correct log values on back end side but on front side even if the OTP is invalid, it pushes the history to next page it is supposed to stay on the same page.
What is wrong in my code and how to fix it? 
my front end code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../pod.css";
export default class OTPVerify extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //const { params } = this.props.location.state;
    //var data = this.props.location.userPhone;

    console.log(this.props.history.location.state.userPhone);
    this.state = {
      userPhone: this.props.history.location.state.userPhone,
      userotp: "",
      verified: false,
      isMounted: false,
      existingUser: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      {
        isMounted: true
      },
      function() {}
    );
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    //console.log(event.target.value);
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  verifyOTP = event => {
    if (this.state.isMounted == true) {
      console.log("XXX");
      if (this.isOTPValid(this.state.userotp)) {
        this.forwardToHomePage();
      } else {
        alert("please enter a valid OTP");
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    //
  };
  async isOTPValid(phone) {
    if (phone.length === 6) {
      var val = this.checkOTP();
      console.log(val);
      return val;
      //console.log(this.state.verified);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  async checkOTP() {
    await fetch("http://192.168.43.212:5000/api/verifyOTP", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        pod_Otp: this.state.userotp,
        userPhone: this.state.userPhone
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            verified: responseJson.validOTP,
            existingUser: responseJson.clientExists
          },
          function() {
            console.log(this.state.verified);
            console.log(this.state.existingUser);
          }
        );
        return this.state.verified;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  forwardToHomePage() {
    if (this.state.existingUser) {
      this.props.history.push("/Home", { userPhone: this.state.userPhone });
    } else {
      this.props.history.push("/customerProfile", {
        userPhone: this.state.userPhone,
        edit_enabled: true
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-form">
        <form method="post">
          <h2 className="text-center">Sign in</h2>

          <img
            src="cinqueterre.jpg"
            className="rounded-circle"
            alt="Book Pandit"
          />

          <div className="or-seperator">
            <i>or</i>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="input-group">
              <span className="input-group-addon">
                <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
              </span>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="userotp"
                required="required"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              ></input>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-success btn-block login-btn"
              onClick={this.verifyOTP}
            >
              Verify OTP
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I check the console on invalid otp, initially it shows promise pending

Comment: What is the value of `responseJson.clientExists`? If it is truthy then this check `if (this.state.existingUser)` will evaluate to `true`. I.E. if your JSON response is something like `{"existingUser": "false"}`, a non-empty string is truthy.

Comment: my Json response is the way I wanted but the redirect happens even without checking the values

Comment: Sorry, was browsing on mobile earlier and focused on the navigation pushes I saw. Later realized `forwardToHomePage` pushes in both branches, but you weren't expecting them to. Added answer.

Answer (score 0):

`isOTPValid` is an async function, as is  `checkOTP`. `checkOTP` correctly awaits the fetch response, but `isOTPValid` does not. In `verifyOTP` you are checking the current return value of `isOTPValid`, which since not awaited on, is the pending promise. You need to await the resolution of the implicit promise that `checkOTP` returns.

```
verifyOTP = event => {
  if (this.state.isMounted == true) {
    console.log("XXX");
    if (this.isOTPValid(this.state.userotp)) {
      this.forwardToHomePage();
    } else {
      alert("please enter a valid OTP");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
};

async isOTPValid(phone) {
  if (phone.length === 6) {
    var val = await this.checkOTP(); // this is a promise!!! you should await its resolution
    console.log(val);
    return val;
    //console.log(this.state.verified);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```